# SQL getting a Row with MIN(col A) if 2 row exist then MIN(colB)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table as below

```
Table1
(
col A float,
col B float
)

I need a row with min(col A). If 2 rows have same col A value then 
row with min(col B).

EX: (case 1 )

     A      B
    1.2    1.5
    1.5    1.0
Result should show be first row

(case 2)

    A      B
    1.2    1.5
    1.2    1.0
Result should show be second row

Is it possible in a single query? Please help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the easiest way:

```
select top 1 cola, colb
from table1
order by cola, colb
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my issue. Is there any catch with this if you have col A and col B are NULLABLE?

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 * from [dbo].[12] where a = (select min(a) from [dbo].[12])  OR b=(select min(b) from [dbo].[12])
```

Comment: What if the min(b) is not in the same row as the min(a)? :)

Comment: The `OR` won't solve it either, as this will return any record with min(a) OR min(b)

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi: it wont solve my problem. if 2 rows exist with same col A value then i want the row with min of col B among those 2 records.

Comment: @Manju I know. That is what my previous comment say... and also the previous one ^.^ The best approach is the order by one

Comment: @MostyMostacho: By mistake i addressed u instead of Vijaykumar.I edited it now.